# cmake: using only headers from opencv for my library

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I'm creating a geometry based tool, that uses `Vec` class from opencv. This class is completely defined in the `matx.hpp` header. Therefore, I need just that header for my application. My question is in general though, for cases like this, where you are just using some structures or similar from a library, what's the best way to specify them to use in your `CMakeLists.txt`

Normally, I would do the following:

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED COMPONENTS core)

add_library(lib1 STATIC
    src/a.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(lib1
    PUBLIC 
    opencv_core
)
```

But this will link everything from `opencv_core`, and although the compiler won't actually add all objects, it being a `PUBLIC` dependency can lead to problems down the line. For instance, future modules might get away with not linking to `opencv_core` even if they had to because `lib1` carries forward that dependency. This seems like an inaccurate way to achieve what I need.

Alternatively, I could use the `${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}` variable, like so:

```
target_include_directories(lib1
    ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

But as I'm moving to more modern practices, I prefer to not use variables because they contain all of the combined values for the entire library. For this use case, what is the best way?

Thank you

Comment: That's true but this isn't about users of my library, it's about the best way to find headers of `opencv`, a library that I am using

Comment: Sorry, I understand your questions now fully. Never thought about this before. Hmm...

Comment: It seems to avoid linking `opencv_core` or including unnecessary dirs, one would have to use `find_path` on `matx.hpp`. But calling it directly is a pain in the ass on so many levels. Looks to me the best you can do is call `get_target_property(dirs opencv_core INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)` and then `target_include_directories(lib1 PUBLIC ${dirs})` and maybe (unlikely) you can avoid include unnecessary locations, provided that the authors of OpenCV do a good job in their `OpenCVConfig.cmake`. It's still painful to also include this logic in your own config file for your user.

Comment: I don't think it's bad to use `OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS` in this case. At least it is an official way (in the sense OpenCV developers made this variable available) to get the information you want. Even better, for your use case, would be if OpenCV would provide a header-only target. Of course, you can also setup such target yourself, with either the technique from the previous comment or just by using `OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS`.